# Python raw_input how to make only one input possible

Tags: python

I am new to python, My first project that I am still working on is a kind of a game in which you throw a dice and stuff like that, so it's pretty much a dice simulator.

Before the user actually starts the game I have made the program ask them questions like; "Type 'start' on keyboard to begin the game, and this I am doing with `raw_input`.

Here's the problem:- I want to make only the input 'start' possible to write, if something else is written, the game doesn't start. I hope you understand me

```
from random import randint

min = 0
max = 6

start=raw_input("Welcome to the dice game, type 'start' on your keyboard to start the game:")
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
name=raw_input("Okey, let's go! Before we can start you must type your name here: ")

print ("Hey %s, I guess we're ready to play!!" % name);
print("The whole game concept is basically to throw a dice and get as high number as possible!")
print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
ja=raw_input("Would you like to throw the dice? Type 'yes' if so:")
print "Your number is:", randint(min, max)
print ("Thank you for playing!")
```

Comment: means just one digit? like 1 or 2 not 10 or 20 right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

You just need `if_else`

```
from random import randint

min = 0
max = 6

start=raw_input("Welcome to the dice game, type 'start' on your keyboard to start the game:")
if start=='start':

    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    name=raw_input("Okey, let's go! Before we can start you must type your name here: ")

    print ("Hey %s, I guess we're ready to play!!" % name)
    print("The whole game concept is basically to throw a dice and get as high number as possible!")
    print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    ja=raw_input("Would you like to throw the dice? Type 'yes' if so:")
    print "Your number is:", randint(min, max)
    print ("Thank you for playing!")
else:
    print("XYZ message")
```